Как в express.js активировать js-код на стороне пользователя?
Пишу Web Telegram App, если такое возможно, хочу инициализировать SDK телеграма до загрузки основной страницы, и на основе полученных данных проверять, является пользователь настоящим или данные подделаны, а также в последующем рендерить страницу с учётом данных пользователя. Вот псевдокод, как я это вижу
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
        const user = response.send('<script src="mycode.js"></script>')
        if (user === '...') {
           response.render('main')
        }
        
    })

Если это невозможно, то тоже пожалуйста скажите, это я также отмечу лучшим ответом

Почему сразу нельзя запустить код на клиенте?

@SwaD, дело в том, что в зависимости от того, кем является пользователь, необходимо передавать переменные в рендер странички

Данные для определения пользователя должны быть сразу в запросе. В одном запросе, один ответ. Пришел запрос, даже если клиенту вернуть скрипт, то с клиента потребуется повторный запрос с передачей нужных данных

Если верить примеру, то на момент первого обращения у пользователя "пустой браузер". В request есть переданные заголовки запроса. Отдав даже код туда, там ничего не произойдет, т.к. код надо запустить(а там еще ничего нет). Опишите полностью(отредактировав вопрос) решаемую вами задачу, может найдется(наверняка) правильное решение.

@SwaD, спасибо, я отредактировал вопрос и раскрыл задачу, может так найдет свой ответ

В целом, все что приходит с клиента может быть подделано(особенно get запрос) и сервер никогда не должен доверять данным, которые пришли, особенно в части проверки пользователя.
